# css selector - get the value

Tags: html, css, selenium, dom

What is the css selector to get the text value '2017-10-09' ?

```
<div class="col-xs-6">                                        
   <strong>
   <!--ko text: date -->
      2017-10-09
   <!--/ko--> 
   <!--ko text: time -->
      12:55
   <!--/ko-->
   </strong><br>                                        
   <!--ko text: locationName -->
      City
   <!--/ko-->                                    
</div>
```

Comment: it is better you put some tag around the date and the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such selector.

With a few exceptions (such as [`:first-line`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-line)), a selector only allows you to select *an element*.

The text `2017-10-09` is not an element, it isn't even the whole text content of an element.

`strong` would allow you to select `<strong><!--ko text: date -->2017-10-09<!--/ko--><!--ko text: time -->12:55<!--/ko--></strong>` but that is more than you are asking for.

You could select the `strong` element, then read its text content, and then parse that (e.g. by splitting it across space characters or using a regular expression such as `/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/`).

Answer (score 0):

There are no CSS selectors that can check the data format in the text node that I know of. You should wrap a tag around the date and that use a proper selector for that tag like:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">                                        
   <strong>
   <!--ko text: date -->
      <span class="date">
        2017-10-09
      </span>
   <!--/ko--> 
   <!--ko text: time -->
      12:55
   <!--/ko-->
   </strong><br>                                        
   <!--ko text: locationName -->
      City
   <!--/ko-->                                    
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can target the strong tag inside the div and then process the date out of text node.